# Enhancing mono with information for error handling

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

We are using `Mono` to handle calling REST services and I would like to enhance the exception handling by adding some extra information, to be used in case an exception has to be thrown.

Roughly, the code we have is of this form:

```
public ResultType callSomeService(Object param) {
   return addTimeoutAndRetryToMono(getMonoForServiceCall(param)).block();
}
```

The `addTimeoutAndRetryToMono` is a function that takes and returns a `Mono` and adds timeout, retry and error mapping. It is in the error map it defines that we throw, for instance, a `TimeoutException`.

I would like to enhance the exception being thrown by the `callSomeService` function with information regarding the service being called. For example, I would like to throw a custom exception with a message like "Timeout while calling {some path}".

Unfortunately, the "path" information is available only in the `getMonoForServiceCall`, which is generated based on an OpenAPI specification.

I have simplified the functions mentioned above to this:

```
Mono<T> getMonoForServiceCall(Object param) {
   ....
   // webClient comes from spring-webflux
   // prepareRequest handles the http method, path, query params, etc., fairly boiler-plate stuff
   ...
   WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBuilder = prepareRequest(webClient, path, param);

   return requestBuilder.retrieve().bodyToMono(returnType);
}
```

and

```
Mono<T> addTimeoutAndRetryToMono(Mono<T> mono) {
  return mono.timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
             .onErrorMap(t -> handleExceptions(t));
}

Throwable handleExceptions(Throwable t) {
  return new RestClientException("Here I would like to have the path of the API being called");
}
```

The simplest way would be to pass the "path" information around, catch and throw the custom exception in `callSomeService`, but there are quite a lot of these methods and it does feel "dirty".

I tried to use `contextWrite` in `getMonoForService`, adding the "path" to the context, but I can't seem to make it available in the error map.

The ideal sort of change would be done at the level of `getMonoForService` (where I have access to the path and other relevant fields) and `addTimeoutAndRetryToMono` (which is adding the error map), since these are in one of shared libraries and would result in a cleaner solution. The `getMonoForServiceCall` function should continue to return a `Mono<T>`.

Comment: Can you please show us some code? It's really hard to understand where exactly is the problem without seeing the code. There are many ways to do what you want and it all depends on your code design

Comment: @IgorArtamonov hi! I added more code, detailing the two methods I think are relevant. While it is still far from a contained, reproducible, snippet, I feel it has all the key bits. Please let me know if I'm wrong and more is needed!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that the only place where this `path` value is available is `getMonoForServiceCall` but this method is auto-generated. I guess the only solution is to look down the `prepareRequest` and check if there is a way to override something to get access to the value and then there could be different ways to pass it out

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I think I can do that, what would be the ways of passing it out?

Comment: It very depends on the code. It could be a context, could be passing an argument to some function, could be replacing the internals with a wrapping object.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I tried to do a `contextWrite` but I couldn't read the data I wrote in. I'll accept an answer with a context write in `getMonoForServiceCall` and reading the data in `handleExceptions`

Comment: With the code you have, `contextWrite` can work only if you use it from `callSomeService` which doesn't have access to the variable. But maybe there is something inside the `prepareRequest` that can be used instead

Comment: In other words, you have at least two possible ways to do what you want. One is on the requesting side, but you have to have an access to the path. Then you can use a context, a method param, etc. Another way it to provide it with the resulting data itself, like wrapping object, a tuple, etc. The requesting side seems to be a generated code so you cannot touch it, in this case look at the side which return the data and how you can modify it